# How can i merge my two Flickr accounts?

Tags: flickr

i had a Flickr account 2 years ago.. i forgot the password ..
Then i opened another new Flickr account ...

but yesterday I recovered my old one ..

and ive some old precious photo on that account and the original copies do not exists on my hard drive and large amount of likes and comments

now i want to merge two into ONE and use them them together 
and its too hard to handle two accounts together

please help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is best answered by contacting Flickr customer service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the (trivially findable!) [Flickr Help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/flickr/SLN7294.html): "It's not currently possible to merge two or more Flickr accounts under one login ID. As a workaround, you can download your photos from one account and upload them into another. [...] Last updated: April 07, 2014"

Probably not want you want to hear, but pretty definitive.